# What does System.getenv("SYSTEM") returns?

Tags: java, environment-variables

yesterday i tried to print all the system environment variables and i saw one named "SYSTEM".

I never seen this variable so i tried to print it, the result is:

`XaD+cVnuAOayI4XQ6c8iVEAxfIHSnPO1bkqP8rrze6IWpG/wufHLs3+tcdOL4z2HVFbmVV1q/IXAE5E6ysGZnRspxUMpt3l5cvLt2kofNi9weo4nFD8mtfmNXkR0Q+dxISt9BkIlA5lwUQil58KBFBxUMvvKkj7d83MHOrZrgG7+oseT4oFH3JkdOFY4IsYgwQk8fwyhDDzdvKn7gy3PiwPsnmhXwf5JLQgzOg39mLWhv5hpQzT/N9NHHjQ1U3DgUirIx+NcZrujDj2fJM1y6g==`

What does exactly returns `System.getenv("SYSTEM")` ?
Why it returns some kind of encrypted text?

Comment: It's a Base64 encoded message, try decoding it with an online decoder.

Comment: Even after decoding it appears to be _gibberish_. It will be hard to interpret its meaning or format without having any sort of documentation on who created this variable, how and why. Afaik it is not one of the _standard_ enviornment variables.

Comment: Does not exist on my system (Windows 10), I get `null`. I suspect this is a custom environment variable that you or some of ur applications have created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.getenv() function returns a value of an environment variable configured in your operating system.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

For example- if we will create a new environment variable called **FooFoo** with the value of **"Hello World!"**

```
export FooFoo="Hello World!"
```

The following code:  `System.out.println(System.getenv("FooFoo"));` will have the output

> "Hello World!"

In your scenario- some software you installed has created an environment variable called SYSTEM, and it have the value of the encrypted string that you mentioned.

This environment variable is not one of the default windows 10 environment variables

> https://pureinfotech.com/list-environment-variables-windows-10/

Nor one of the default linux environment variables

> https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-all-environment-variables-env-command/